# Ng-model variable changing in $onInit method but model don't change

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple currency converter app, after getting data I set the result variable which depends on From input value, but after changing From input, result input don't change

```
  $onInit() {
  this.currencyService.getData('http://api.fixer.io/latest').then((res) => {
    this.data = res
    this.values = Object.keys(this.data.rates)
    this.result = this.amount * this.data.rates[this.fromVal] / this.data.rates[this.toVal]
    this.isLoad= true

  })

}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Amout</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model='$ctrl.amount'>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Result</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  ng-model='$ctrl.result'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The reason is in the question: the result is initialized in $onOnit, but the "from" input value changes later. So you need to recompute the result  when the "from" value changes. Use ng-change. Why do you use and **input** field to display the **output** (the result) of your component?

Comment: I inititialized result in $onInit, but shouldn't it change when _amout_ value is changed?

Comment: And yes, I made this code work by putting `ng-change='$ctrl.getResult()'` on 1st input, but I am wondering why _result_ is not updating when _amount_ is changed

Comment: No, it shouldn't change. You compute result in $onInit. After that, result contains a value, and there's no reason for it to magically contain another value when some other variable changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thought that if I bind _result_ and _amout_ with ng-model, angular would set 2 watchers, so when _amount_ is changed it will cause the change of  _result_